# Where to store files in order to get them with InputStream in Android apps

Tags: android, apache-poi, inputstream

I am working on a project where I have to insert company logo in an excel sheet.
I am using apache-poi for this but i am getting a **file not found** exception.

I stored my logo in my drawable folder and later in my assets folder, still the same thing.

Here is my code

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("logo.png");
    byte [] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is); 
    int pictureIndex = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
    is.close();

    CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    patriarch = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

    anchor.setCol1(10);
    anchor.setRow1(3);
    Picture pict = patriarch.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);
    pict.resize();

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(root+"/Busotina/Busotina1.xls");
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So my question is, should I store my images in some specific folder or I am dealing with another issue here?

Comment: did that solution work or did you do it another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be putting the files you want to interact programmatically with in you `/res/raw` folder.  Then access as

```
InputStream inputStream = activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.logo);
```

See [directory raw](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) on developer.android. Reads:

> Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources with a raw InputStream, call Resources.openRawResource() with the resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.
>   However, if you need access to original file names and file hierarchy, you might consider saving some resources in the assets/ directory (instead of res/raw/). Files in assets/ are not given a resource ID, so you can read them only using AssetManager.